# convert function from java to kotlin

Tags: java, android, string, function, kotlin

i tried pasing a java function in my Kotlin project and in automatically converted to Kotlin but still has an error.

```
 if (ch.toInt() >= 0x0660 && ch.toInt() <= 0x0669)
            ch -= 0x0660 - '0'
        else if (ch.toInt() >= 0x06f0 && ch.toInt() <= 0x06F9)
            ch -= 0x06f0 - '0'
```

it is giving error on the `- "0"`
the error is: Non of the following functions can be called with the argument supplied

Comment: what is the `ch`

Comment: Why are you trying to use Kotlin if you don't know the language? They're interoperable so you might as well stick to Java for the most part and learn Kotlin as you go.

Answer (score 1):

This is because kotlin doesn't type cast between char and int. You'll have to invoke `.toInt()` on the `'0'` like you already did with the char. The `Int` class only supports `minus` with the following types:

- `Byte`
- `Short`
- `Int`
- `Long`
- `Float`
- `Double`
  [Link](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Primitives.kt#L588) to the `minus` operator functions of `Int`.
   On the other side, `Char` only supports `Char` and `Int` when it comes to `minus`.